# Does any one have a working script of LoadRunner Automation API?

Tags: perl, loadrunner

Currently I am writing Perl script that creates LoadRunner scenario, execute the test, collect the result, recover the environment and repeat the cycle again with different scenario variables.

I don't have a problem creating new scenario, adding generator, adding 2 groups + script + the run-time settings. But I am having a problem with:

1. Setting scenario schedule from "Scenario" to "Group".
2. Setting schedule per group

This the snippet of the code:

```
use strict;
use v5.10;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Enum;
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
use Data::Dumper;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'LoadRunner Automation Library';
use constant False  =>  Variant(VT_BOOL,'');
use constant True  =>  Variant(VT_BOOL,1);

my $lrEngine = Win32::OLE->new('wlrun.LrEngine') or die "oops\n";
my $lrScenario = $lrEngine->Scenario();
my $rc = $lrScenario->new(0, 1); # do not save previous, Regular vusers based scenario 
if ($rc != 0) {
    print "Win32::OLE::LastError: ".Win32::OLE::LastError()."\n";
    print "lrScenario->new(0, 1):rc: $rc\n";
}
# snip-snipped - add generator
# snip-snipped - add @groups definition
foreach my $group (@groups) {
    print "scriptName: $group->{scriptName}\n";
    my $scriptLocation = $group->{scriptLocation};
    my $scriptName = Variant(VT_BSTR|VT_BYREF, $group->{scriptName});

    { # add $group->{scriptName} script
        $rc = $lrScenario->Scripts->Add($scriptLocation, $scriptName);
        if ($rc != 0) {
            print "Win32::OLE::LastError: ".Win32::OLE::LastError()."\n";
            print "lrScenario->Scripts->Add($scriptLocation, $scriptName):rc: $rc\n";
        }
    }
    #############################################################################
    my $groupName = Variant(VT_BSTR|VT_BYREF, $group->{groupName});
    { # add $group->{groupName} group
        $rc = $lrScenario->Groups->Add($groupName);
        if ($rc != 0) {
            print "Win32::OLE::LastError: ".Win32::OLE::LastError()."\n";
            print "lrScenario->Groups->Add:rc: $rc\n";
        }
        $rc = $lrScenario->Groups->Item($groupName)->AddVusers($scriptName, $hostname, 3);
        if ($rc != 0) {
            print "Win32::OLE::LastError: ".Win32::OLE::LastError()."\n";
            print "lrScenario->Groups->Item($groupName)->AddVusers:rc: $rc\n";
        }
    }
    #############################################################################
    # snip-snipped - change group script run time setting
}

my $scheduleName = Variant(VT_BSTR|VT_BYREF, 'Schedule123');
my $lrManualScheduleData = $lrScenario->ManualScheduler->AddSchedule($scheduleName, lrGroupSchedule); # Scenario schedule mode
if (!$lrManualScheduleData) {
    say "Win32::OLE::LastError: ".Win32::OLE::LastError();
    say "lrScenario->ManualScheduler->AddSchedule:rc: $rc";
}
$rc = $lrScenario->ManualScheduler->SetCurrentSchedule($scheduleName);
if ($rc != 0) {
    say "Win32::OLE::LastError: ".Win32::OLE::LastError();
    say "lrScenario->ManualScheduler->SetCurrentSchedule:rc: $rc";
}
print "\$lrScenario->ManualScheduler->SetScheduleMode($scheduleName, lrGroupSchedule):";
$lrScenario->ManualScheduler->SetScheduleMode($scheduleName, lrGroupSchedule);
#LrManualScheduleMode ->  lrGroupSchedule = 1, lrScenarioSchedule = 0
say "Win32::OLE::LastError: ".Win32::OLE::LastError();

$lrManualScheduleData->{'InitAllBeforeRun'} = 'True';
$lrManualScheduleData->{'DurationMode'} = 1;
$lrManualScheduleData->{'Duration'} = 60 * 60;
$lrManualScheduleData->{'RampupBatchSize'} = 1;
$lrManualScheduleData->{'RampupMode'} = lrRampupByGroupBatches;
$lrManualScheduleData->{'RampupTimeInterval'} = 5;
$lrManualScheduleData->{'RampdownBatchSize'} = 1;   
$lrManualScheduleData->{'RampdownMode'} = lrRampupByGroupBatches;
$lrManualScheduleData->{'RampdownTimeInterval'} = 5;

$rc = $lrScenario->ManualScheduler->{'ScenarioStartTimeMode'} = 0; # Start scenario without delay 

#test
say "$scheduleName: ".$lrScenario->ManualScheduler->Schedule($scheduleName)->{'Duration'}; # returns 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. Setting those properties and then calling either setschedulemode or setcurrentschedule doesn't seem to work. The only workaround I have found is to use the setscheduledata method passing in xml. You will need to get the current xml for the scheduledata and then change the xml, passing in the modified xml to the setscheduledata method. Hopefully this helps

```
lrManualScheduleData data = engine.Scenario.ManualScheduler.get_Schedule("Schedule 1");

String scheduleXML,errStr;

int returncode = data.getScheduleData(out scheduleXML, out errStr);

// Manipulate the XML to set whatever schedule you want

data.SetScheduleData(scheduleXML, out errStr);
```